# Octave not recognising values when loaded from file

Tags: octave

I have a tab separated values file which I load and convert to a tablicious table where the values are scalars.
When picking values from the table it does not recognize all values. If I create the exact same values direct as a matrix it does.
`(tab1.a == tab2.a)'` gives `ans =  1  1  0  0  0  0  1` showing that values 3 to 6 are different. Difference of `2.2204e-16` indicates it's a numeric accuracy thing, but how can I allow for that?
I'm on Octave version 6.4.0

```
    clear all; clc;
    pkg load tablicious
    
    function pick = tabpick(tab, a, b);
      pick = ((tab.a==a) & (tab.b==b));
      if ~sum(pick)  % no match
          error("Selection not dataset !!\n");
      endif
      pick = table2struct( tab(pick,:));
      return
    endfunction
    
    % create table direct
    m = [ 1.315 1.7
            1.315   2.19
            1.66    2.1
            1.66    2.3
            1.66    3.03
            1.76    3.28
            1.9   2.4  ];
    a = m(:,1);  
    b = m(:,2); 
    tab1 = table(a, b);
    % prettyprint the table
    pp(tab1)
    % show type of variables
    typeinfo(tab1.a), typeinfo(tab1.a(1))
    
    % load table from tsv file
    fid = fopen('table_test.txt', 'r');
    tab_file = textscan(fid,"%f %f",'delimiter','\t', 'Headerlines',1);
    a = tab_file{1};
    b = tab_file{2};
    tab2   = table(a, b);
    pp(tab2)
    typeinfo(tab2.a), typeinfo(tab2.a(1))
    
    % compare the two: They are different !
    (tab1.a == tab2.a)'
    
    % we can pick any value by menu
    pick=menu('pick b', cellstr(num2str(tab2.b)));
    table2struct( tab2(pick,:))
    
    % pick from tab1 works fine
    tabpick(tab1, 1.315, 2.19)
    tabpick(tab1, 1.76, 3.28)
    
    % pick from tab2 fails on second one
    tabpick(tab2, 1.315, 2.19)
    tabpick(tab2, 1.76, 3.28)
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference value gave the clue. Working with

```
    function pick = tabpick(tab, a, b);
      pick = (abs(tab.a-a)< 1e-15) & (abs(tab.b-b) <1e-15);
      ...
```

Comment: Indeed. Typically on such questions someone will always post this link as a comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. Also, note that the 2.2204e-16 value you reported is likely the floating-point precision of your machine. You can confirm that by running the "eps" command. Therefore if you cared at all about your program being 'translatable' to machines with different precision, you might want to express your tolerance in terms of `eps`. If the 'approximate equality' test is effectively an 'assertion', you can also use the `assert` command with a 'tol' value.

Comment: Thanks Tasos.  Indeed my 'eps' is '2.204e-16'.  However given both approaches take the exact same character values as input (either from text file or from script).  I initially expected the same outcome. Obviously textscan arrives at the scalar values via a different route than a script matrix.